# Custom field in Shipping address and display value in admin sales order view

Tags: magento2, shipping-address

I want to create a custom field in shipping address on checkout and display its value on admin order view and invoice pdf.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check this https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Answer (score 0):

Please use the refrence link : https://meetanshi.com/blog/add-custom-field-in-checkout-page-below-payment-method-list-in-magento-2/

You can modify what type of input field you want to show in checkout page and then its value in admin sales order view.